# How to add subtasks in Microsoft lists/SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, tasks, microsoft-lists

I am new to SharePoint and I am trying to create a comprehensive task management platform using SharePoint but I am unable to add subtasks and most of the resources that I have seen online say that I can add subtasks but it also looks like its an older version 2013 or 16.

Can we do this in the new SharePoint or in Microsoft lists?

Answer (score 1):

There is no list template available in modern experience which allows adding subtasks.

However if you are using a team site, you can still use classic/old "Tasks" list template in SharePoint online to create a list where you can add subtasks for each task in list.

---

Follow below steps to create a list using classic "Tasks" list template:

1. Go to Site contents --> Select **New** --> Select **App** OR select **Add an app** from settings (gear) icon
2. On "My Apps" page, select **From my organization**

   [image]
3. Select **classic experience** link

   [image]
4. It will open classic experience "Your Apps" page where you can search for & add "Tasks" list

   [image]

---

**Additional**:

You can directly go to classic experience "Your Apps" page using URL in below format:

```
<site-url>/_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx
```